# Why won't my angular custom validator invalidate my form?

Tags: angular, validation

I have the following custom validator class:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {
  static phone(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (control.pristine) {
        return null;
      }
      const PHONE_REGEXP = /^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
      control.markAsTouched();
      if (PHONE_REGEXP.test(control.value)) {
        return {
          phone: true
        };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

I have the following component:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  ControlContainer,
  FormGroupDirective
} from '@angular/forms';
import { NumberValidators } from '../app.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-telephone-input',
  templateUrl: 'telephone-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['telephone-input.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }
  ]
})
export class TelephoneInputComponent implements OnInit {
  telephoneControl: AbstractControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    NumberValidators.phone
  ]);
  constructor(private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parent.form.addControl('telephoneControl', this.telephoneControl);
  }

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.telephoneControl.hasError('required')
      ? 'You must enter a telephone number'
      : '';
  }
}
```

I have the following in my Template (Just a snippet about the Submit button)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message" [disabled]="!formModel.valid">Submit</button>
```

My problem is that the Submit button enables whenever I put anything in it -- even letters.  It seems to be utterly ignoring my custom validator.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: From the looks of it, you forgot to negate the test condition in your validator? AFAIK, that should be `if (!PHONE_REGEXP.test(control.value)) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm sorry, I'm not following you....

Comment: If I remember correctly, the validator should only return something if the value is invalid. You're returning if the value is valid.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  Got it.  Alas, changing the logic around doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I needed to change this:

`NumberValidators.phone`

to this:

`NumberValidators.phone()`

Once I added the parentheses, the validator started validating.

And the commenter was correct, I had to reverse the logic of my validation check.